# Invoke iPad application from iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, user-interface

I developed one iPhone application that runs in iPad in 1x/2x mode. In the same application i have a module that is designed specific to iPAD.

How should i invoke these iPAD screens?

Thanks
Sudha

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can't do that. An app is either for iPhone or universal. You can't switch that once the app is compiled.

Comment: Ok. Is there NO way to switch from 1x/2x mode to normal iPad Screen mode.

Comment: @Sudha don't forget to mark top answer or upvote answer(s) that have helped you. If they haven't helped you please add comments to them and  add further details. Anyone facing the same issue will then not have to ask the same question, and those putting in the time to answer will get the rep points

Answer (score 2):

You can't have half an iPhone app and half an iPad app, even if you could that would be terrible for the users and you shouldn't! storyboards enable you to have 2 files, one for iPhone and one for iPad and you can simply load whichever is applicable.

Xcode even handles this for you by allowing you to specify which is which in the project settings.

There is no way to switch between the 1x/2x as you have mentioned. The app is either set to run in this mode on iPad (because its an iPhone app), or its not because its universal and supports both, or is iPad only